# In MS project, sub project tasks are not showing up in sprint task board

Tags: ms-project, ms-project-2016

I added multiple sub projects to my current master project. I don't see the sub project tasks in sprint task board though I assigned sprints to tasks and "show on board" is yes. The tasks from the master project show up but not the sub project tasks.

Repro steps:

1. Open Microsoft Projects [application](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/project/project-management-software)
2. Create a project or two.Add tasks under each project (using Task tab)
3. Create another blank project( master project).
4. Link first two projects as sub-projects to this master project (created in step3). YOu can link by going to Project tab => Subproject menu.
5. Go to sprints tab -> Planning (Sprint Planning Board). No tasks appear.
6. But if you open any of the sub projects directly and go to Sprints tab-> sprint planning board, you can see the tasks.